# How do I get my headset microphone working?

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, 20.10

I am running Xubuntu 20.10 and have a pair of Beats Solo 3, but Linux doesn't seem to recognize my headphones.
Here's the output of various commands:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4208 Analog [CS4208 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ amixer -c1
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono: Playback 28 [22%] [-49.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-63.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-63.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 2
  Front Left: 2 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 2 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 61 [97%] [10.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 61 [97%] [10.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'


$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-30-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBookAir6,2 v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5 v: MacBookAir6,2 serial: <filter> UEFI: Apple v: 121.0.0.0.0 
           date: 04/12/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 49.3 Wh condition: 50.6/54.3 Wh (93%) model: SMP bq20z451 status: Full 
CPU:       Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-4650U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 1 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 18400 
           Speed: 1842 MHz min/max: 800/3300 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1966 2: 1908 3: 1890 4: 1887 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Apple driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz 
           2: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5000 (HSW GT3) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Apple driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-3: Broadcom and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera driver: facetimehd v: kernel bus ID: 02:00.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-30-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Apple driver: wl v: kernel 
           port: efa0 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: lxcbr0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.92 GiB used: 344.20 GiB (73.9%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Apple model: SSD SM0512F size: 465.92 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 442.00 GiB used: 340.11 GiB (76.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 14.90 GiB used: 4.08 GiB (27.4%) dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 88.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 361 Uptime: 2d 53m Memory: 3.78 GiB used: 2.02 GiB (53.5%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 10.2.0 clang: 11.0.0-2 Packages: 6072 Shell: fish v: 3.1.2 inxi: 3.1.07
```

I need my mic for Zoom, but I can't seem to find anything on how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it Bluetooth?

Comment: No, it's a wired headset.

Comment: Strange when I look it up it says it is Bluetooth

Comment: It is but it can be wired. I can't get bluetooth to work and the mic is better when it's wired anyways

Comment: All the sites I can find only talk about it being bluetooth. What is the issue if you try to use bluetooth?

Comment: No sound is outputted, and I assume the mic won't work either.

Comment: You connect to Bluetooth OK? Then you went into sound settings and made sure it was selected? No sound does not always mean no mic.

Comment: I tried everything, but no sound comes out, and no mic input is detected.

Comment: Does it connect via USB?  If so, does the feature need software? If so, does the manufacturer publish their software for linux?

Comment: No, no, and no. It connects via a standard headphone jack.